# Insert into DB2 table a result from temp table

Tags: db2, insert, query

Is there a way to insert a temp table results to DB2 table, for example:

```
WITH TEMP1 AS (
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
FROM T_CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID BETWEEN 100 TO 300
),
TEMP2 AS (
SELECT CUTOMER_ID, ORDER_ID
FROM TEMP1 T1
JOIN T_ORDER R1 ON T1.CUSTOMER_ID = R1.CUSTOMER_ID)

SELECT CUTOMER_ID, ORDER_ID
FROM TEMP2
```

I tried the below way, but it did not work:

```
INSERT * INTO T_STORAGE (CUTOMER_ID, ORDER_ID)
SELECT *
FROM TEMP2
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find any way. Only to modify my query without temp tables, but then the query will be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Since TEMP2 only exists in the scope of the statement, you can't reference it from another statement. You can insert directly like:

```
INSERT INTO T_STORAGE (CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_ID)
WITH TEMP1 AS (
    SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
    FROM T_CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID BETWEEN 100 AND 300
), TEMP2 AS (
    SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_ID
    FROM TEMP1 T1
    JOIN T_ORDER R1 
        ON T1.CUSTOMER_ID = R1.CUSTOMER_ID
)
SELECT CUTOMER_ID, ORDER_ID
FROM TEMP2
```

If you need to use the content of TEMP2 in several statements, you can declare a global temporary table and insert to that first.

I'm not sure why you need the CTE though, this should be equivalent:

```
INSERT INTO T_STORAGE (CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_ID)
SELECT T1.CUSTOMER_ID, R1.ORDER_ID
FROM T_CUSTOMER T1
JOIN T_ORDER R1 
    ON T1.CUSTOMER_ID = R1.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE T1.CUSTOMER_ID BETWEEN 100 AND 300
```